# What are the "GraphQL calls" in the `rangeBehaviors` attribute of the `RANGE_ADD` mutator config?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

The [docs describe](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#range-add) `rangeBehaviors` as:

> A map of GraphQL calls to the behavior we want Relay to exhibit when adding the new edge to connections under the influence of those calls. Behaviors can be one of 'append', 'prepend', or 'remove'.

The example in the docs is:

```
rangeBehaviors: {
  // When the ships connection is not under the influence
  // of any call, append the ship to the end of the connection
  '': 'append',
  // Prepend the ship, wherever the connection is sorted by age
  'orderby(newest)': 'prepend',
}
```

and in another example in the [todos example repo](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/v0.4.0/examples/todo/js/mutations/AddTodoMutation.js#L45-L50) you have:

```
rangeBehaviors: {
  '': 'append',
  'status(any)': 'append',
  'status(active)': 'append',
  'status(completed)': null,
}
```

What is a "GraphQL call" in this case? What does it mean to be "under the influence of" such a call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query for a connection field in Relay, you can potentially specify arguments beyond just the standard pagination arguments of `first`, `last`, `before`, and `after`.

In the TodoMVC example above, we qualify the query by the current filter on status. The meaning of the TodoMVC code you've shown is that the mutation should append the new todo for queries that filter for statuses of `"active"` or `"any"` (or the default status), but not for queries that filter to only the status of `"completed"` (which makes sense in context, since the mutation adds a new, active todo).

Comment: Thank taion. So you're saying that the mutation config instance looks at keys in the `rangeBehaviors` object as parameter-name/argument-value combinations for parameters that exist in the connection field? So supposing a connection field named `todos` parameterized is on `status` (in addition to `first`, `last`, etc), a key in `rangeBehaviors` called `status(any)` is interpreted by the mutator as "if the `status` parameter of the connection field has value `any`, the behavior should be `append`"?

Comment: That's mostly correct - the "call" describes the values of all of the field args (other than the standard connection ones). It has to be an exact match. If there is no match, then Relay will re-fetch the entire connection.

Comment: We should probably remove references to "call" from the docs. "Call" was a concept in the original FB internal version of GraphQL (eg. `things.first(10).fizz(5)`); in the open source release these became field arguments (eg. `things(first: 10, fizz: 5)`).